# Reading a csv file into an array in Java (the add method not working)

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, csv, oop

I am trying to implement a csv reader into my class in Java using eclipse. I keep getting an error for the add method "add(Person) in the type list is not applicable for the arguments (String[]). What am I doing wrong?

```
public static List<Person> readPersons(String fileName)
throws FileNotFoundException {
    
    
    int count = 0; 
    List<Person[]> content = new ArrayList<>(); 
    try(BufferedReader cv = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))){
        
        
        String line = "";
        while ((line = cv.readLine()) != null) {
            content.add(line.split(",")); 
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        
        
    }
        
    return content;     
        
    }
```

Also, how do I implement this FileNotFoundException extender? It is required in the program.

Comment: `line.split` will return an array of `String`, not an array of `Person`.

Answer (score 1):

The `line.split( "," )` method will return an array of strings.

What it does is: The original string `line` is split into an array of strings. In that array, every string is a substring of `line` which is separated by a comma.

For example, if `line` is `"Peter,Smith,38"`, the following array of strings will be returned: `[ "Peter", "Smith", "38" ]`.

But, since your List only can contain objects of the type `Person`, it cannot take the `String[]` array returned by `line.split( "," )`.

So assuming you have an Constructor for `Person` that looks like this: `Person( String firstName, String secondName, int age )` you would have to change your while loop to something like this:

```
while ( ( line = cv.readLine( ) ) != null )
{
  // Get the data from the CSV object
  String[] csvData = line.split( "," );
  
  // Create a Person object with the retrieved data
  Person personFromCsvLine = new Person( csvData[0], csvData[1], Integer.parseInt( csvData[2] );
  
  // Now you can add the person object to your list
  content.add( personFromCsvLine );
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. It must have something to do with Eclipse??? Also, I think you miswrote the variable on the last line. Here is the error:  "The method add(Person[]) in the type List<Person[]> is not applicable for the arguments (Person)"

Comment: @ReceptionistTWLawGroup This code is adding a single person in the `add` call, but you have declared the list to take an array of persons on each `add` call. Do you really want each entry in the list to be an array? This is nothing to do with Eclipse.

Comment: @greg-449 Actually no! It was my intention to add each line to a single array. It is a csv file with names seperated by age.

Comment: @ReceptionistTWLawGroup Then it should be `List<Person>` rather than `List<Person[]>` and the code in this answer looks correct for that.

Comment: Perhaps you can post a sample row from your CSV.
Please change any real names to fake ones!
Based upon the original question and your remark, I can determine what you want to achieve,

Comment: @McBeelen Sample row looks like: "Fred Smith, 28"  
"

Comment: As @greg-449 said, you should change the type of the variable `content` to `List<Person>`, then your code should work fine.

Comment: Also, in the method signature you want to return a `List<Person>`. This won't be compatible to the type `List<Person[]>`, which is a list of arrays of persons and **not** a list of persons.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by [be-ta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65179498/1407771) is correct.

I would like to point out that for reading a CSV you might want to consider using an existing solution in your code, like:

1. [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/)
2. [Jackson CsvMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-csv/)

   - [Example code](https://gist.github.com/asafary/9675488)

These libraries will help with quoted / unquoted columns and conversion of values to the proper datatypes.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. It must have something to do with Eclipse??? Also, I think he miswrote the variable on the last line. Here is the error: "The method add(Person[]) in the type List<Person[]> is not applicable for the arguments (Person)" –